# Trouble with company insurance - worth making a fuss about it?

Tags: company-policy, insurance

A while back I started a new job at bigcorp. They insure all employees via some third party insurance company. We have a list of doctors we can go to, then either we pay there and can claim the amount from the insurance or we don't need to pay at all and insurance handles payment with the doctor.

When starting at bigcorp, we got a document that shows the inclusions/exclusions for the health insurance, also the limits (like, unlimited specialist visit but physiotherapy capped at XXX per year, etc). I had private health insurance before, so I know how the documents look, and the doc they gave us looked a bit short for a full insurance policy.

Anyway, without going in to too much detail, recently I handed in a claim to the insurance. I continued treatment, accumulated some more claims, added them in also.

After I already handed in my third claim for the same cause, all of them got rejected and insurance tells me that I should have done Y and Z before starting treatment but instead I did only Y so all claims are rejected.

As you can imagine, I referred to the "policy" document I got from my company and there it only says I should have done Y before starting treatment, no mention in the whole document of Z.

So to cut things short, after a few emails back and forth with the insurance they still insist I did it wrong, even though they also won't tell me any reference where the rule I apparently violated is stated.

For me it looks like there is another, larger set of rules that is not told to employees and that seems to cause rejecting claims. I heard similar stories from coworkers, although about smaller amounts.

I wonder what to do now, is it worth getting in touch with the people in HR that take care of insurance communication to make them aware of these things or do I look like a troublemaker?

I'm not looking for someone higher up in my company to "weigh in" on the insurance and pressure them to reimburse me, since I don't think that will work anyway, but I'm more thinking about providing feedback about my experience with the insurance (since bigcorp only recently contracted with said insurance.)

Comment: Not answering your question, but...  Find out what the insurance company's formal complaints process is, and start that.  Also start looking at whether there is a regulator in your country who deals with insurance companies who don't pay out on claims.

Comment: It's bigcorp. They have people to handle this kind of things. Start with HR to find out whom you should talk to. I retired from a Dow Jones 30 company. I never had that kind of problem. It's one of the things Bigcorp is worth working for. If they can't help you to resolve the problem, I guess it's time to find a new job. Medical insurance claims can cost you months of salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide some more information: Are you in the United States? Were you provided with details about the company's insurance plans, or options about which one to choose? What did you select, and why, if you don't mind answering? You say you have policy documents but it's unclear to me whether you were presented with choices about the plans, or what the plans are supposed to cover.

Generally speaking, most companies - even large ones - don't administrate their own health insurance. It's probably acceptable to provide feedback to HR about the insurance plans they provide, and it's likely they can help you navigate issues with the insurance, though they might not feel obliged to depending on the company's policy.

Also, most insurance companies have an appeal process, and in the US, at least, most states have legally-mandated ways you can get an insurance decision against you appealed outside of them, too, or at least overridden.